# In queuing theory, what is the difference between departure rate and service rate?

Tags: queueing-theory

As per my understanding, a job departs as soon as it's servicing is over and thus they should be same. 
However, I came across the following statement: 
*The throughput for a queuing system with infinite capacity is
the mean number of customers processed in a unit of time, i.e. the departure
rate. Since the departure rate is equal to the arrival rate (and assuming ρ < 1),
the throughput is λ = m · ρ · µ:* where m is the number of systems. 
 So I am guessing  departure rate and service rates are different.

How to distinguish between the two? the description says *mean number of customers processed in a unit of time* which is also similar to what service rate means.

[1](http://www.eeng.dcu.ie/~ee414/notes/ee414-09-slides-4.pdf) page 8 is where it is mentioned.

Comment: Perhaps departure rate is (or includes) people leaving the queue (out of unwillingness to continue waiting), whereas service rate is related to people reaching the front of the queue and being served. e.g. 10 people wait in lines for haircuts, suppose they will only wait at most 10 minutes in line. Then some of those people will get bored and leave line. Others will get their haircut (# haircuts/hour is service rate) departure rate is the number of people who leave the lines per hour.

Comment: For a $M/M/c$ queue with arrival rate $\lambda <c\mu$, the departure process (at equilibrium) is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. This is known as Burke's theorem.

Comment: the explanation I found relates the throughput of the system with the departure rate, so I believe they are getting serviced and leaving.@Mark

Comment: @Math1000 how does this departure rate differ from service rate?

Comment: The departure rate is equal to the arrival rate, in steady state (for example, when the process has initial distribution equal to that of the stationary distribution) - and does not depend on the service rate.

Comment: @Math1000 My question is why are they equal? Departure will depend on service time, so no matter at which arrivals occur, departure should be an independent process in my opinion.

Comment: The transient behavior of the departure process will depend on service time, but the long-run behavior does not. I will admit that it is not an intuitive result. One way to look at it is that the number-in-system is a birth-death process, and so is time reversible. The arrivals in "forward" time are departures in "reverse" time.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service rate is the number of customers per hour that the server can process, assuming there are always more customers waiting. It doesn’t depend on the arrival rate. So if the service rate is 10/hour, it means the server *could* process 10 per hour (on average of course), but sometimes there won’t be customers who need processing, so the server will process fewer.

Departure rate is the number of customers leaving the system. So if 8 customers per arrive on average, then 8 customers per hour will depart on average (assuming $\rho < 1$, i.e., the system is stable), as noted by Math1000 in one of the comments.

The reason the departure and arrival rates are equal is that the system does not create or destroy customers — every customer that enters also departs, and vice versa.

Comment: Assuming service rate is 10 and arrival rate is a value greater than 10, the departure rate will always be 10 irrespective of the arrival rate, is that right? I understand your explanation, but it seems to me it is valid when arrival rate is less than service rate.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am assuming stability conditions hold ($\rho < 1$), otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: Updated answer to reflect stability condition.